# What can I use to wrap the Form widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to add a `Padding()` widget to a `Form()` widget, but I get multiple sizing errors, even when I try a `SizedBox` or `Expanded`.

I want to resize the whole `Form` proportionally, how do I do this?

```
FractionallySizedBox(
    widthFactor: 0.8,
    child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
            children: [
                TextFormField()
            ]
        )
    )
)
```

I initially tried Padding instead of `FractionallySizedBox`, similar errors.

Comment: look fine to me https://dartpad.dev/?id=11ab8b8c382678f8a68f8c78cc5b146f

Comment: Please check it again, I edited it to what I tried to achieve, I didn't think the upper code had the errors since the console showed the errors in the form area: https://dartpad.dev/?id=11ab8b8c382678f8a68f8c78cc5b146f

Answer (score 0):

try with scrollPadding.EdgeInsets.zero ---> I dont know, this is what you want

```
body:FractionallySizedBox(
widthFactor:0.8,
 child:Form(
   key:_formKey,
   child:Column(children:[
      TextFormField(
       scrollPadding:EdgeInsets.zero,
     ),
   ]),
 ),
),
```

Comment: Do not post images of code. Code should be posted as *text*.